# Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to different window

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have `Window` let's call it `W` and class `LogicW`, at constructor of `W` i pass reference to that window to `LogicW`

```
public W
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LogicW l = new LogicW(this);
}
```

And at `LogicW` I'm doing all the logic stuff, so now I whant to start new thread at W that will call method from `LogicW` do some work and add `UserControll` to `W`.

```
public void add()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => l.Add());
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}
```

And in `LogicW` add method:

```
public void Add()
{
...
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => baseWindow.GroupsStackPanel.Children.Add(i)));
}
```

Where:
`baseWindow` is reference to W passed in LogicW constructor
`GroupsStackPanel` is normal StackPanel at W
`i` is UserControll

But I get:

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

I also tried to pass reference to that window in argument:

```
public void Add(MyWindow w)
{
...
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => w.GroupsStackPanel.Children.Add(i)));
}
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.)
Maybe it would help you to take a look at MVP design pattern. For a general understanding of seperating logic/ui stuff.

2.)
The solutions other posted are working but they're not the "cleanest" solution. You can't access an UI thread from another thread.
It would be better to let your thread do some work and when he's done signal LogicW just to update the UI with your new data.

This could be easily done wrapping your thread stuff inside a new class and give it an event to which LogicW listens.
When using MVP pattern this update could be done inside your "ShowModel" method.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
baseWindow.GroupsStackPanel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
{
    //You Code Here
    baseWindow.GroupsStackPanel.Children.Add(i);
});
```

Comment: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: @Carlos28 I updated the answer, have a try and let me know if it works

Comment: Error 12 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @Carlos28 Updated again

Comment: @Carlos28 Please let me know if there is any other issue

Comment: at baseWindow.GroupsStackPanel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { baseWindow.GroupsStackPanel.Children.Add(i)}); i also get  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @Carlos28 You missed the semicolon ad the end, I updated again

Answer (score 0):

Here you go dude: the method that is in anther thread and does stuff then adds UI controls

```
private void StartAlgo()
    {
        while (Algo.CurrentAge <= Algo.MaxNumberOfAges)
        {
            Matrix = Algo.LearnAge(GeneratedPoints);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                View.Children.Clear();
                DrawPoints();
                DrawMatrix();
            }));

        }
    }
```

the code in the Dispatcher uses controls from the UI thread (btw this is WPF) so if you want to add a button for example just add it in the Dispacher

and call to the thread:

```
private void AlgoBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread alg = new Thread(StartAlgo);
        alg.Start();

    }
```